# How to execute a method after a response is complete in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, akhet

Using Pyramid with Akhet, how do I execute a method *after* a response has been returned to the client?  I believe this was done with the `__after__` method in Pylons.  I'm trying to execute a DB query and don't want it to block the request response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [response callback](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#using-response-callbacks) for your case.

*EDITED after Michael Merickel's comment*: The response callback blocks the request to which is added, but you shouldn't worry about that callback blocking other requests since each request runs in a different thread. If you still need not to block the request with the callback, you can spawn a different thread or process (if you can afford it) or look into message queuing systems as mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: The response callbacks, as well as `__after__` in Pylons, are executed after a response object has been generated, but make no mistake that the code executed here still happens in-band with the request and before the response object is returned to the WSGI server. Neither Pyramid nor Pylons offer a solution for executing code out-of-band. You'll need to use an external queuing system or thread to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the blocking of the request with the callback. I updated the answer taking your comment into account. I still want to make clear that Pyramid requests run in different threads and that in many cases that's more than enough to take care of non-blocking issues, instead of making the callback truly non-blocking.